# Cerrar anterior elemento activo con Jquery

Tags: jquery, html5, css3, wordpress, wordpress-plugin

Tengo el inveniente con un acordion que se ha hecho en Wordpress con el plugin Elementor y pues necesito que al abrir otro div el elemento hijo del anterior pierda la clase `.elementor-active`

```html
<div class="elementor-toggle" role="tablist">
  <div class="elementor-toggle-item">
    <div id="elementor-tab-title-1901" class="elementor-tab-title" data-tab="1" role="tab" aria-controls="elementor-tab-content-1901">
      <span class="elementor-toggle-icon elementor-toggle-icon-left" aria-hidden="true">
        <i class="elementor-toggle-icon-closed fa fa-caret-right"></i>
        <i class="elementor-toggle-icon-opened fa fa-caret-up"></i>
      </span>
      <a href="">Un gran titulo 1</a>
    </div>
    <div id="elementor-tab-content-1901" class="elementor-tab-content elementor-clearfix" data-tab="1" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="elementor-tab-title-1901" style="display: none;"><p>Un texto increible!!!</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="elementor-toggle-item">
    <div id="elementor-tab-title-1902" class="elementor-tab-title" data-tab="2" role="tab" aria-controls="elementor-tab-content-1902">
      <span class="elementor-toggle-icon elementor-toggle-icon-left" aria-hidden="true">
        <i class="elementor-toggle-icon-closed fa fa-caret-right"></i>
        <i class="elementor-toggle-icon-opened fa fa-caret-up"></i>
      </span>
      <a href="">Un gran titulo 2</a>
    </div>
    <div id="elementor-tab-content-1902" class="elementor-tab-content elementor-clearfix" data-tab="2" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="elementor-tab-title-1902" style="display: none;"><p>Otro texto Increible!!!</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

No logro siquiera eliminar la clase `elementor-active` de ningun elemento HTML, les dejo el codigo con Jquery que he hecho...

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.elementor-tab-title').bind('click', function() {
        $('.elementor-active').removeClass('elementor-active')
    });
});
```

Muchas gracias de antemano...

Comment: ¿A que altura se agregaría o se muestra la clase **elementor-active**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Segun click en cada título se agrega o retiran las clases indicadas.

Recuerda que la propiedad **.bind()** esta **obsoleta(deprecated)**, en las versiones actuales de jquery debes usar el método **on**.

Da click en **Ejecutar** para ver la respuesta propuesta, dando click en cada título.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".elementor-tab-title").on("click", function() {
    $(".elementor-active").removeClass("elementor-active");
    $(this).find("div").addClass("elementor-active");
  });
});
```

```css
.elementor-active {
  background-color: #CFC;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="elementor-tab-title">
  <div class="">
    titulo 1
  </div>
</div>

<div class="elementor-tab-title">
  <div class="elementor-active">
    titulo 2
  </div>
</div>

<div class="elementor-tab-title">
  <div class="">
    titulo 3
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias tu ejemplo me sirvio de ayuda, al final hice lo siguiente: `$(".elementor-tab-title").on("click", function() {
if($(".elementor-tab-content:hidden") == true ){
$(this).addClass("elementor-active");
$(".elementor-tab-content").addClass("elementor-active");
$(this).find(".elementor-tab-content").css({"display":"block"});
}else{
$(".elementor-tab-content").css({"display":"none"});
$(".elementor-tab-content.elementor-active").removeClass("elementor-active");
$(".elementor-tab-title.elementor-active").removeClass("elementor-active");
};
});`